How-to get multiple ocurrences in html, finding sections
I have an html string:
<section id="post-2603507" class="caja-anuncio ">
<section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...
    </section> 
<section class="caja-datos">
 ... OMITTED...
     </h5>

 </section>
</section>
          
 ... OMITTED...  



   <section id="post-1149642" class="caja-anuncio ">
<section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...
    </section> 
<section class="caja-datos">
 ... OMITTED...
     </h5>

 </section>
</section>

How-to get multiple ocurrencies in groups (from first  node to last  node) ?
Each section is:
 <section id="post-1149642" class="caja-anuncio ">
    <section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...
        </section> 
    <section class="caja-datos">
     ... OMITTED...
         </h5>
    
     </section>
    </section>

I try regex like:
<section id="post-\d+" class="caja-anuncio\s*">((?s).*) 
<section id="post-\d+" class="caja-anuncio\s*">((?s).*)<\/section>\s*<\/section>\s* 
<section id="post-\d+" class="caja-anuncio\s*">((?s).*)<\/section>\s*<\/section>\s*<section

Any suggestion?

How to get where? In javascript? Java? C#? A template system? A database query? XSLT? Please [edit] your question to include more detailed information of what you are trying to do. Also not that regex is the wrong answer for handling HTML code.

only need the regex expression, independent by language. Powershell in my case, but regex is agnostic. Testing in https://regex101.com/

You shouldn't try to use regex for HTML, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

You should not use regex to parse HTML.
This was however not trivial seeing that the parsing introduced a trailing space in the class string, so we need trim to handle that
# HTML content - I inline it but you can read from a file - I added a missing <h5>
$htmlContent = @'
<section id="post-2603507" class="caja-anuncio ">
<section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...   </section> 
<section class="caja-datos">
 ... OMITTED...
     <h5></h5>

 </section>
</section>
          


   <section id="post-1149642" class="caja-anuncio ">
<section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...    </section> 
<section class="caja-datos">
 ... OMITTED...
     <h5></h5>

 </section>
</section>
'@

# Convert HTML to XML by wrapping it in a root node
try {
  [xml]$xmlContent = [xml]("<root>" + $htmlContent + "</root>")
  Write-Host "XML Content:" $xmlContent.OuterXml  
} catch {
  Write-Host "Error parsing XML:" $_.Exception.Message
}  

# Debug to see we successfully parsed the HTML
Write-Host "Root Element:" $xmlContent.DocumentElement.Name
Write-Host "First-Level Children:" 
$xmlContent.DocumentElement.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object { $_.OuterXml }

# Loop the root sections
foreach ($node in $xmlContent.root.section) {
    Write-Host "Section ID:" $node.id
    Write-Host "Class Attribute:" $node.class
}

# Use ArrayList to store matching sections
$sections = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# Manually filter sections with class "caja-anuncio"
foreach ($section in $xmlContent.root.section) {
    # Trim the class attribute to remove any trailing spaces
    $classValue = $section.Attributes["class"].Value.Trim()
    Write-Host "Trimmed Class Value:" $classValue

    # Check if the trimmed class attribute matches "caja-anuncio"
    if ($classValue -eq "caja-anuncio") {
        [void]$sections.Add($section)
        Write-Host "Added section, current count in ArrayList:" $sections.Count
    }
}

# Output the final count and the results
Write-Host "Final count in ArrayList after loop:" $sections.Count
foreach ($section in $sections) {
    Write-Host "Section ID:" $section.Attributes["id"].Value
    
    # Access nested sections
    $foto = $section.section | Where-Object { $_.Attributes["class"].Value.Trim() -eq "foto" }
    $datos = $section.section | Where-Object { $_.Attributes["class"].Value.Trim() -eq "caja-datos" }
    
    Write-Host "Foto Section:" $foto.OuterXml
    Write-Host "Datos Section:" $datos.OuterXml
    Write-Host "`n---`n"
}

Output
Section ID: post-2603507
Foto Section: <section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...
    </section>
Datos Section: <section class="caja-datos">
 ... OMITTED...
     <h5></h5></section>

---

Section ID: post-1149642
Foto Section: <section class="foto"> ... OMITTED...
    </section>
Datos Section: <section class="caja-datos">
 ... OMITTED...
     <h5></h5></section>

---

